# why does perl parse $x | $y | $z as $z | ($x | $y)?

Tags: perl, parsing, operator-overloading

(EDIT: The `pipe` function below should return a blessed object for overloading to work correctly. See the accepted answer.)

I'm trying to use perl's `overload` capability to build up a simple parse tree.
I don't need much - in fact, all I need is one operator that is left-associative.
But there seems to an inconsistency in the way perl parses `$x op $y` versus a longer
chain like `$x op $y op $z op ...`.

Here's what I have:

```
package foo;

use overload '|' => \&pipe,
             "**" => \&pipe,
             ">>" => \&pipe;

sub pipe { [ $_[0], $_[1] ] }

package main;

my $x = bless ["x"], "foo";
my $y = bless ["y"], "foo";
my $z = bless ["z"], "foo";
my $w = bless ["w"], "foo";

                               # how perl parses it:
my $p2 = $x | $y;              # Cons x y
my $p3 = $x | $y | $z;         # Cons z (Cons x y)
my $p4 = $x | $y | $z | $w;    # Cons w (Cons z (Cons x y))
my $p5 = $z | ($x | $y);       # same as p3???

my $s2 = $x ** $y;             # Cons x y
my $s3 = $x ** $y ** $z;       # Cons x (Cons y z)
my $s4 = $x ** $y ** $z ** $w; # Cons x (Cons y (Cons z w))

sub d { Dumper(\@_) }

say "p2 = ".d($p2);
say "p3 = ".d($p3);
say "p4 = ".d($p4);
say "p5 = ".d($p5);

say "s2 = ".d($s2);
say "s3 = ".d($s3);
say "s4 = ".d($s4);
```

The output is something like:

```
p2 = [bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),bless( ['y'], 'foo' )]
p3 = [bless( ['z'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),bless( ['y'], 'foo' )]]
p4 = [bless( ['w'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['z'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),bless( ['y'], 'foo' )]]]
p5 = [bless( ['z'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),bless( ['y'], 'foo' )]]

s2 = [bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),bless( ['y'], 'foo' )]
s3 = [bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['y'], 'foo' ),bless( ['z'], 'foo' )]]
s4 = [bless( ['x'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['y'], 'foo' ),[bless( ['z'], 'foo' ),bless( ['w'], 'foo' )]]]
```

Shouldn't `p2` have x and y reversed to be consistent with the other cases?
Note that `p3` and `p5` produce the same output - so how I can tell them apart?

I don't see the same problem with the right-associative operator `**`.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use feature ":5.14";
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dump pp);

sub foo() 
 {package foo;

  use overload '|' => \&p;

  sub p {bless [@{$_[0]},@{$_[1]}]}
 }

my $x = bless ["x"], "foo";
my $y = bless ["y"], "foo";
my $z = bless ["z"], "foo";

my $p = $x | $y | $z;

pp($p)
```

Produces:

```
bless(["x", "y", "z"], "foo")
```

Comment: Yes - I should have `pipe` return a blessed object.

Answer (score 2):

Overloaded operator handlers sometimes receive operands in reversed order, but Perl will notify the handler when it does so by setting the swapped argument to true.

[overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html):

> > Three arguments are passed to all subroutines specified in the use overload directive (with one exception - see nomethod). [...] The third argument is set to TRUE if (and only if) the two operands have been swapped. Perl may do this to ensure that the first argument ($self ) is an object implementing the overloaded operation, in line with general object calling conventions. [...]

You disregarded the third argument passed to the handler. The underlying problem is that you forgot to return a *foo* object from `pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Marpa, I think it is better in parsing things like this.

http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2010/05/bnf-parsing-and-linear-time.html

https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::PP

I think it is a typo in your script:

```
my $p3 = $x || $y || $z;
```

Comment: It's not a typo - `|` is the "bit-wise or" operator, `||` is the "logical or" operator. Also, I'm looking to create a new operation on a new data type which is why I'm using overloading.